# Issues creating Admin module controller on Prestashop

Tags: module, routes, controller, composer-php, prestashop

The controller for URI "/modules/mm_custom/deleter" is not callable. Class "Mm_Custom\Controller\ConfigureController" does not exist.
[InvalidArgumentException 0]

That's what I get after 3 days trying to set an AdminController on my Prestashop module.

Here is the controller "configureController.php":

```php
<?php
// modules/mm_custom/src/controller/configureController.php

namespace Mm_Custom\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;

class ConfigureController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController
{
    public function deleteAction()
    {   
        return new Response('Hello');
    }
}
```

Here is the routes.yml :

```yaml
# modules/mm_custom/config/routes.yml
delete:
    path: mm_custom/deleter
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
      _controller: 'Mm_Custom\Controller\ConfigureController::deleteAction'
```

Here is the composer.json at the module folder root:

```json
{
  "name": "sixten/mm_custom",
  "description": "A tool developped to allow your customers to easily and efficiently custom your product.",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Mm_Custom\\Controller\\": "src/Controller/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
      "prepend-autoloader": false
  },
  "type": "prestashop-module"
}
```

If the problem is not from a mistake in the code himself, it might comes from the fact that I couldn't run the `composer dumpautoload` console command in the module's folder directly because the website is online on a ftp server.
I put the composer.json somewhere else on my computer, ran the command and copy/paste the composer.json and the vendor file I get in the ftp's module folder. Maybe it's not the good way to do it ?

Thanks for reading me !

Comment: Actually copying the vendor folder is recommended (don't run composer on the webserver). You may want to look into the `composer archive` command as it will create a "package" so that you know its complete. Apart from that suggestion there might be some Prestashop related details, perhaps within its module system. E.g. `"type": "prestashop-module"` may hint there is a Composer plugin/integration/installer from Prestashop which also needs to run and copy things somewhere (e.g. at the right location so that autoloading works).

Comment: Also make sure the names are properly cased. You have controller folder and class file that starts with lowercase.